# Are the meanings of «I know what you know» distinguishable?

Tags: semantics, ambiguity

First let me warn you I have no academic formation in Linguistics, I can't define that area well, so if this sounds off-topic, it probably is.

"I know what you know" is an ambiguous sentence, carrying two distinct meanings: that "I" am in knowledge of, at least, the very same things "you" are; or that "I" have information of **which** subjects "you" know (without this meaning "I" know anything **about** subjects "you" knows).

I have several related questions associated to the sentence: is there any way to separate the two meanings without a full explanation (kind of what I did)? What about other languages? In Portuguese, the same thing happens. Esperanto often seems to have a way to carry just the needed precision, yet I can't think of any way to distinguish those meanings right now. With what types of verbs does this work? For instance, it doesn't work with "think" (a proposition is required in at least in one of the cases) and most certainly not with "eat".

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, and i'm a little confused by your description of the two different readings, but i *think* what you've identified is the de dicto vs. de re readings of an embedded interrogative. The first reading that you identify would correspond to the de dicto (lit. "the word") reading - 'what you know' isn't referring to a *specific* proposition, but just whatever the referent happens to know. The second reading is de re (lit. "the thing") - 'what you know' is referring to a specific proposition. Can anyone confirm/disconfirm this?

Comment: Yes, they're somewhat distinguishable. There are two varieties of such embedded question clauses, which [Ross calls Conjunctive and Disjunctive](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CQ-DQ-New.pdf). A conjunctive clause _what you know_ refers to 'A and B and C and D and ...', while a disjunctive clause _what you know_ refers to 'A or B or C or D or ...'. The subject complement in _What she knows comes as a big surprise_ is conjunctive, but the subject complement in  _What she knows is still a big mystery_ is disjunctive.

Comment: Here's one way of making the difference a little clearer. Consider the following premises:
(a) *John knows what Bill knows*.
(b) *Bill knows nothing*.
Under one reading, the conclusion (c) is licensed:
(c) *John knows nothing*.
Under the second reading, the conclusion in (d) is licensed:
(d) *John knows that Bill knows nothing*.

Comment: Having thought about this some more, i think i was wrong to identify the ambiguity as a matter of de re vs. de dicto. Rather, i think that what we have hear is a *structural* ambiguity between 'know' with a free -relative as its complement (syntactically a DP), and 'know' with an indirect question as its complement (syntactically a CP). The free relative reading corresponds to the conclusion (c), and the indirect question reading corresponds to the conclusion (d). I'll try to spell this out some more in an answer if i have a spare 20 mins at some point.

Comment: Yes. That's another way of stating the [distinction that Ross makes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CQ-DQ-New.pdf). Relative clauses are presupposed material, hence conjunctive; questions are unknown material, hence disjunctive. But there's no syntactic difference between a free relative (or headless relative, or fused relative) clause and an embedded question clause. When you leave out that much stuff in a clause, you lose the ability to mark that distinction, is essentially what I think happens. The only thing left is the semantic distinction, and that's usually interpreted by context.

Comment: @jlawler: You say that there isn't any syntactic difference, but i was under the impression that free relatives behave as DPs syntactically, whereas embedded questions are sentential. I'm not a native speaker, but we should be able to tease the two apart in German, where DPs occupy the mittelfeld, and CPs *must* right-extrapose. So, in the following cases:
(a) Er hat [was du gewusst hat] gewusst.
(b) Er hat *t* gewusst [was du gewusst hat].
(a) should receive the free relative interpretation, and (b) should receive Q-interpretation. Can any native speakers chip in?

Comment: @jlawler, indeed, in that article, "know" is listed as compatible both with conjunctive and disjunctive wh-forms; which explains why this happens.

Comment: @Everyone, when answering, please remember to use a simple terminology (or to explain the one you're using), as I'm unfamiliar to most of the one you use in the comments.

Comment: Another, much clearer method of disambiguating between embedded questions and free relatives in English is that only the *former* are compatible with so-called 'non-aggressively d-linked wh-phrases' (e.g. "who the hell", "what the bejesus", etc.). Consider:
(a) Does anyone know what John knows? (ambiguous).
(b) Does anyone know what the hell John knows? (unambiguous).
Note (b) only receives indirect question interpretation. (P.s. @JMCF125: sorry about the jargon, i'll make sure to clarify everything if i get round to formulating an answer)

Comment: Oh, there are tests, as Ross points out, but all of them involve features that coordinate (or don't) with the semantics. In general, there's no way to tell from the syntactic structure itself, the way there is with full relatives and full complements; as I say, a lot's left out. BTW, both free relatives and embedded questions are both NPs (in McCawley's sense) and Ss. DPs only exist in some theories, and are probably an unnecessary complication here.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks for the clarification. It seems like we're coming at this from two different angles: I tend to assume an interpretive semantics, so when a sentence has two **truth-conditionally distinct** readings, i assume that this is due to some underlying structural ambiguity. This doesn't necessarily hold if you have different background assumptions. My frame of reference here is van Riemsdijk's (2000) chapter on free relatives: http://www.colbud.hu/apc-aa/img_upload/4d11dfd490c468ca39fcefabae592944/Riemsdijk2006_Free_Relatives__SynCom_.pdf

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "an interpretive semantics", since I am coming at this from McCawley's (1998) framework (as is Ross). For semantics, [straightforward predicate calculus](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) works well enough. The last I heard of "intrepretive semantics" was around 1973 or thereabouts, and I expect it's changed a bit since then.

Comment: By "interpretive semantics" i guess i mean that the semantic component takes a syntactic representation and 'reads off' a semantic representation. Hopefully i'm not using the term incorrectly. I have an unfortunate tendency to take my own background assumptions as gospel - i try not to, but apologies if i've come across as intransigent. I'd be interested to learn more about how the difference here is derived in McCawley's framework.

Comment: Oh, that presupposes that there are discrete components of syntax and semantics. That's a good way to design a program, but nothing evolved has a structure like that. As an unreformed generative semanticist, I use whatever works and ignore the rest. In this case, it's simple enough to use logics as the DSs and the wh-clause as SS, then deal with how they got that way. Anything outside that is ponenda sine necessitate, imo.

Comment: @jlawler Aha, that explains a lot. I suppose what i don't particularly understand is the "how they got that way" part. It's easy enough to say that an embedded interrogative can be mapped to one of two different LFs, but why? and why are they disambiguated in certain environments? Is it all just context? I guess that just doesn't feel like a very satisfying explanation. Ross does admittedly say that "the whole phenomenon is total murk to me". It's a great research topic!

Comment: No, let's not. I don't like the chat interface. As for the rese, derivations.

Answer (score 4):

I would submit that prosody could play a role in disambiguating the two readings, at least in English. As a native speaker, if I heard someone say (out of the blue):

> 1) ***I*** know what ***you*** know.

I would interpret it as, "I have knowledge about the same things you have knowledge about." On the other hand, if I heard:

> 2a) I know what you ***know***.

or

> 2b) I ***know*** what you ***know***.

I would interpret it as, "I know which subjects you have knowledge about."

The reason is that we tend to emphasize things that we are comparing or contrasting entities in parallel constructions (a phenomenon known as *contrastive focus*) and to de-emphasize things that are repeated or taken for granted in the context of the conversation (things that are *given* or *presupposed*).

In (1), the two instances of *know* are referring to the same knowledge, so they are de-emphasized, but the pronouns (i.e. the "knowers") are different, so contrastive focus is utilized. This version of the utterance would have the same prosodic pattern as something like, "I watched what you watched" (in response to the question, "What did you watch on TV last night?").

Emphasis on the last content word in a phrase or a clause (without getting theory-specific here) can also signal focus on that whole constituent (known as *broad focus*). In both (2a) and (2b), the constituent "what you know" is being focused as new information, and so the last word, *know*, gets emphasized. Whether the first *know* is emphasized or not could depend on the speech rate as well as the context. In faster speech or in a context where the topic of the speaker's knowledge is given (e.g. if the speaker is answering the question "What do you know?") the first *know* may not get emphasized. But in more careful speech or in a context where the topic of the speaker's knowledge hasn't been established (e.g. if the speaker is responding to the question "Why are you smiling?") the first *know* may get emphasized. The prosodic patterns given in (2a) and (2b) would be appropriate for something like "I ate what you cooked" (in response to "What did you eat for dinner tonight?" or "Why did you get sick last night?").

Answer (score -1):

I agree with P Elliot above, that your two sentences are:

with regards fact "X" (as an example, "swans are white")

I know X, that you know as well. (I know that swans are white too.)
vs
I know that you know X (but may not know it myself). (I know that you know what colour swans are.)

(As has been pointed out in comments, purely syntactically, the first version of "I know what you know" implies that I share all of your knowledge, not just a specific fact.  However, I feel that in use, nobody would ever suggest that they know everything another person knows, and so there must be an implied context to the use of this sentence.  The discussion around the differences between the two sentences, and other potential cases of this ambiguity still apply whether we are talking about a specific context or a general totality of knowledge, so this point is largely irrelevant to the rest of the discussion.)

In thinking about these two a little more, I came up with this, that I think also explains the ambiguity well:
1) I can answer [a question/all the questions] that you can.
2) I know [a question/all the questions] that you can answer.

In speaking each of the sentences, it would be emphasis that would separate the two.  "I KNOW what you know" is different from "I know WHAT you know."

Besides re-phrasing, which could be done in many ways, an example above in this answer, I can't think of how you could distinguish the two in writing.

I am trying to think of how to classify verbs where this kind of ambiguity, and coming up blank.  The reason that it works with "know" is that the object of "know" is a fact, and "the thing you know" and "that you know a thing" are both facts.  Of course, with any verb, if the object of the verb, call it "X" is a "Y" then "the thing that you X" must also be a "Y", but "that you X a thing" is always going to be a fact.  So a verb that can be applied to a fact in this manner, should be a possible candidate for this ambiguity.

As you pointed out, it doesn't work with "think", because although you can "think" a fact, the phraseology is somewhat different.  "I think what you think" (I think like you) vs "I think that you think [that]." (I know what you think)  Attempting to force the sentences into the same structure to allow the ambiguity brings us back to using the word "know".

One other word I've found that works is "say".  "I say what you say" can mean "I say the same thing as you" or "I tell you what to say".

"I suspect what you know" also has similar ambiguity - but only because suspect basically means "think I know" so the sentence "I think I know what you know" still contains your original sentence.

I can't help with other languages, but I suspect that any with common forms in the declension of a noun, or a specific form for a verb when it's used in a noun phrase, will have this same feature.

Comment: I have to disagree with your agreement. "I know what you know" implies I do not only know **something** you do, but **all** of it. It's like saying "those chairs are brown" implies **all** of those are brown, not some. As such, "I know what you know" is never "I know a thing that you know" but "I know **the** thing&#0001;**s** you know", and, unfortunatly, the plural makes it as unclear as the first sentence. The same happens with "I know that you know a thing", except this one is invalid at least twice. I may know you know a thing, but not what thing.

Comment: If all chairs are brown is true, and there exists a chair, then there exists some chair that is brown. This is basic.

Comment: @jlawler, of course. Nonetheless, if there is a single chair that is brown, that is NOT a one-to-one interpretation of "All the chairs are brown.". Although it is necessary that if you got a chair, and all of them are brown, that one is brown; saying that chair is brown has less information than saying all of them are. Hence, it is not a one-to-one meaning interpretation of "all chairs are brown".

Comment: OK, purely logically, "I know what you know(1)" would syntactically represent "I possess all the knowledge you do".  However, in use, people would usually use the phrase in a certain context, nobody would suppose that they know EVERYTHING someone else knows.  And yes, the second phrasing is slightly off still, editing the question to fix...

Comment: Notice, however, that the "all" is a consequence of the Conjunctive sense, and the "some" is a consequence of the Disjunctive sense. A and B implies A or B, in exactly the same way All A implies Some A, and Necessary A implies Possible A. Demorgan's Laws at work.

Comment: And this is where I think we disagree.  I don't see how either meaning implies some (syntactically, rather than in use).  In either case "what you know" is what I know, and syntactically, that means everything you know.  Whether I know all the answers you know, or just all the questions you can answer, purely from syntax, I must know ALL of them to be able to say "I know what you know".  I also don't see any restriction on knowing something you don't, however, which puts me at odds with the "Bill knows nothing" suggestion above too.

Comment: @Ryno As for why we don't have the same ambiguity with *think*, isn't this because "think" doesn't sub-categorise for an embedded question? We can test this with a 'whether' complement, which can only receive a Q interpretation: a) I know whether you know. b) *I think whether you think. This means that the complement can only be a free relative, and clearly we do get the FR interpretation (i.e. 'the conjunctive sense') only.

Comment: I assume "whether... or not" is something different in this case?  Because "I think, whether you think or not" is valid.

Comment: My own native intuition is that it's still ungrammatical (or at least infelicitous) even with "or not" appended to the end. We can create some nice minimal pairs here, since *think about* does seem to sub-categorise for Q-complement:
(i) *Are you thinking whether John knows something?
(ii) Are you thinking about whether John knows something?
(iii) Are you thinking what i'm thinking (unambiguous - conjunctive interpretation only).
(iv) Are you thinking about what i'm thinking (ambiguous - conj. and disj. interpretations both available).

Comment: (i-iv) above are meant to show that the relevant ambiguity only arises when the predicate sub-categorises for a Q-complement. (i) shows that *think* doesn't take a Q-comp. (ii) shows that *think about* does. (iii) shows that the ambiguity doesn't arise with *think*, (iv) shows that *think about* is unambiguous - patterning with the availability of a Q-complement.

Comment: "(iv) think about is unambiguous" <- think you meant IS ambiguous.  The ambiguity is clearer to me with another "about" on the end of (iv) but I get what you mean.  "Are you thinking" seems to behave very differently to "Do you think", interestingly.  "Do you think whether John knows something" doesn't scan at all "Do you think about whether John knows something" does.  Both versions seem to work with "Are you thinking"

Comment: @Ryno Yes, i meant that *think about* IS ambiguous! Thanks for pointing out my extremely unfortunate typo. The fact that *think about* gives rise to the ambiguity whereas *think* doesn't was central to the case i was trying to make. Also, do you mean by your final remarks that you find "are you thinking whether John knows something?" grammatical? It feels pretty bad to me.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying.  Follow this conversation. "Should we go tonight?  I need to know ASAP so I can plan" [Long silence]  "Are you thinking whether to go?"  (Couldn't think of a context for "John knows something" but the syntax is the same, as far as I can see.)

Comment: @Ryno That's totally out in my English - maybe it's a dialectal difference? I speak BrE btw. Jane Grimshaw (1979) (http://web.mit.edu/norvin/www/24.902/Grimshaw.pdf) argues that *think* doesn't subcategorise for questions. If *think* subcategorises for questions in your dialect of English, the prediction would be that the conjunctive/disjunctive ambiguity should be present for you with *think*. If it isn't, then frankly i'm stumped.

Comment: @PElliott - yeah, "Do you think" and "Are you thinking" behave differently in this case, to me.  I find that odd as well, thinking about it.  Anyway, we've strayed a mile from the original question here :)

Comment: To be more appropriate in my use of the comment section - my answer just randomly picked up a downvote, without recommendation for improvement.  As the only answer on the question, and one that's garnered a lot of discussion at least, I must be doing _something_ right with it...